# Show that a regular Lindelöf space is metrizable if it is locally metrizable.

Tags: general-topology

This is a question from Munkres, $\S34$ Question 8. Hint given is that regularity is essential, and that closed subspace of a Lindelöf space is Lindelöf.

The following is what I have so far: Let $X$ be such space. Since $X$ is locally metrizable, for any point $x\in X$ there exists a neighbourhood $U$ that is metrizable under subspace topology. Since $X$ is also regular, for the aforementioned neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, there exists a closed neighbourhood $\bar{V}$ of $x$ such that $\overline{V}\subseteq U$, so $\overline{V}$ is also metrizable. Since $\overline{V}$ is closed subset of a Lindelöf space $X$, $\overline{V}$ is Lindelöf. Therefore $\overline{V}$ has countable basis.

What I have in my mind is this: since $X$ is Lindelöf, for any open cover of $X$ there exists a countable subcover. If it is possible to let the various $\overline{V}$ be the subcover (not sure how this works, since it is about open cover), then $X$ will have a countable collection of countable basis, therefore it has countable basis. But to be honest I am not sure whether it is even the correct direction. Also I am not sure whether the regularity can be used elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the sets $V$, not their closures.

You have for each $x\in X$ an open nbhd $V_x$ whose closure has a countable base. Second countability is hereditary, so each $V_x$ also has a countable base $\mathscr{B}_x$, and since $V_x$ is open in $X$, the members of $\mathscr{B}_x$ are open in $X$. $X$ is Lindelöf, so there is a countable $C\subseteq X$ such that $\{V_x:x\in C\}$ covers $X$; let $\mathscr{B}=\bigcup_{x\in C}\mathscr{B}_x$, and show that $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for the topology on $X$. (If you get completely stuck, mouse over the spoiler-protected block below.)

> Let $U$ be open in $X$. For each $x\in C$ let $U_x=U\cap V_x$; this is an open subset of $V_x$, so there is a $\mathscr{B}_{U,x}\subseteq\mathscr{B}$ such that $U_x=\bigcup\mathscr{B}_{U,x}$. Let $\mathscr{B}_U=\bigcup_{x\in C}\mathscr{B}_{U,x}$; clearly $U=\bigcup\mathscr{B}_U$.

Comment: To be explicit, Brian is applying the Urysohn metrisation theorem (which has regularity as an essential requirement, see $\Bbb R_K$, e.g.), which was covered in §34. But I don't quite get the hint he gives (use that closed subspaces of Lindelöf spaces are Lindelöf); I think the approach of the answer is the natural one.

Comment: “He” being Munkres in the other comment.

Comment: Actually $\mathscr{B}$ is a sub-basis rather than a basis. To be a basis, we need the intersection of any two elements in $\mathscr{B}$ to be in $\mathscr{B}$ as well. But this is a technical detail and does not affect the overall flow of logic.

Comment: @PetraAxolotl: No, if $\tau$ is the topology on $X$, all that’s necessary in order for $\mathscr{B}$ to be a base for $\tau$  is that $\tau=\left\{\bigcup\mathscr{U}:\mathscr{U}\subseteq\mathscr{B}\right\}$, and the argument in the spoiler-protected block shows that this is the case here.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You're right!

Answer (score 3):

Probably not allowed for you yet, but as a preview of things to come in the book:

Theorem 41.5 (Munkres, 2nd edition) tells us that a regular Lindelöf space is paracompact.

Theorem 42.1, the Smirnov metrisation theorem tells us that a paracompact, locally metrisable space is metrisable.

And of course a metrisable space is locally metrisable, trivially.